# How to sort xml files in php

Tags: jquery, xml

I tried to sort my xml in php. I found a solution here: [Sorting XML File into ascending order using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957449/sorting-xml-file-into-ascending-order-using-php)

However, if there are attributes like item 51390, which has 2 courses while others has got 1, the solution does display them all. Because in the array, he only insert

```
'course'         => (string)$item->courses->course[0]
```

So does my xml, it has also got attributes that other not have. how do I sort my xml and get everything displayed? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use usort. This should work:

```
<?php
$url = '001.XML';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$items = array();
foreach($xml->Images->ImageGalleryEntry as $item) {
    $items[] = $item;
};

// Custom sort on the names of the items:
usort ($items, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['Name'], $b['Name']);
});

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item['FileName'] . "<br/>" . $item['Name'] . "<br/>" . $item['Description'] . "<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did not get this worked. I have replaced the field to relevant ones.